# Sql query percentate change of two data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a set of data like this

```
name   price   number
 A      4400      1
 B      3000      1
 A      3000      2
```

I want to calculate the percentage change of two data with the same name. For example, the percentage change in price of A = (4400 - 3000)/3000 and since there is only one B, its percentage change in price would be zero. 
The following would be my result.

name percentage change in price

A　0.466

B　0

Could someone please tell me how to write sql query to do this?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide desired results.

Comment: Maybe `SELECT name,SUM(CASE WHEN number=1 THEN price ELSE -price END)/SUM(CASE WHEN number=2 THEN price ELSE 1 END) FROM t GROUP BY name`

Comment: Thank you Mihai. I would also like to have B o since there is only one B, its percentage change is zero. Could this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the percentage between the first and last results for each `name`:

```
select name,
       ((max(case when number = 1 then price end) - 
         max(case when number = maxn then price)
        ) /
         max(case when number = maxn then price end)
       )
from (select t.*,
             max(number) over (partition by name) as maxn
      from t
     ) t
group by name;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon!!! You are right!!  I do want the percentage between the first and last results for each. Really appreciate it!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
select name, (max(price) - min(price)) / max(price) from t group by name;
```